# What text comes next?

Tags: knowledge, pattern

What follows is the transcript from my interview with a person called Gray, a notably terse video game streamer who has gotten big in recent years despite only playing one series of games.

> **Q:**  So, how are things going for you, what with the pandemic and everything?
>
> **A:** Regular.
>
> **Q:** Good to hear.  Are you ready for my questions?
>
> **A:** Shoot.
>
> **Q:**  Do you have any advice for up-and-coming streamers?
>
> **A:** Hydrate.
>
> **Q:** And anything you think they should avoid?
>
> **A:**  Marijuana.
>
> **Q:**  All right.  Thinking back to when you started making money with your streaming--how did that make you feel?
>
> **A:**  Excited.
>
> **Q:**  Did you buy anything with those first proceeds?
>
> **A:** Diamonds.
>
> **Q:** Moving on, I'd like to talk about your former partnership with fellow streamer Steamy.  Reportedly, you two did not get along.  How was your relationship?
>
> **A:** Trying.
>
> **Q:** To what do you attribute Steamy's antipathy towards you?
>
> **A:** Bias.
>
> **Q:** And how do you find her behavior?
>
> **A:** Base.
>
> **Q:** Do you have any good memories of that time?
>
> **A:** Fleeing.
>
> **Q:**  Ha, I suppose.  How intense are your feelings about the whole situation now?
>
> **A:** Medium.
>
> **Q:** That's fair.  Are you dealing with any problems now?
>
> **A:** Illness.
>
> **Q:** Aren't we all.  What do you do in your free time?
>
> **A:** Groove.
>
> **Q:**  I know you've had an interest in creating art lately, too.  What would you say you do?
>
> **A:** Trace.
>
> **Q:** I think you're just being humble. Just a couple more questions here, from your fans--
>
> **A:** Interminable.
>
> **Q:** I know you're kidding, but I'm not sure that one works.  Ah, well.  What's your favorite kind of media?
>
> **A:** Macabre.
>
> **Q:** And how do you feel about the upcoming years, hopefully of more success?
>
> **A:** Ready.

So here's the thing: I forgot a question at the end!  I was supposed to ask him what his favorite soda is!

**What's Gray's favorite soda?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gray's favourite soda is:

> **SPRITE**

Why? Because all of the answers he has given are:

> **synonyms of Pokémon types.** The 17 given are:
>
>  Regular = **NORMAL**, Shoot = **FIRE**, Hydrate = **WATER**, Marijuana = **GRASS**, Excited = **ELECTRIC**, Diamonds = **ICE**, Trying = **FIGHTING**, Bias = **POISON**, Base = **GROUND**, Fleeing = **FLYING**, Medium = **PSYCHIC**, Illness = **BUG**, Groove = **ROCK**, Trace = **GHOST**, Interminable = **DRAGON** ('drag on'), Macabre = **DARK**, and Ready = **STEEL**.
>
>  The only type that is missing is Fairy, a synonym for which is **SPRITE**! (Note also that this ordering is the typical one that appears most in literature associated with the game, so the missing answer is also the 18th term of a sequence, not just a set...)

Note also that:

> 'Gray' is the colour of **ASH**, which is the name of the main protagonist from the original Pokémon games, which must be the 'one series of games' he has played!

Comment: Never would have guessed this; last time I played pokemon was years ago. Nice one!